# jQuery Clean up or better way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this long script below that i know can be written better. We have a site that is very heavy JS that i need to change elements with JS and this is what i have below. But i know this can bet written differently to be more efficient. I am not very good with JS that is why it is written on this LONG way.

Any help would be great!

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery(document).ready(function() {
           var html = $("#tab7 a").html().split(" ");
           html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
           jQuery("#tab7 a").html(html);
           jQuery("#tab7 a").css({"line-height" : "16px","text-align" : "center","padding-top" : "29px","height" : "49px"});
        });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery(document).ready(function() {
           var html = $("#tab9 a").html().split(" ");
           html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
           jQuery("#tab9 a").html(html);
           jQuery("#tab9 a").css({"line-height" : "16px","text-align" : "center","padding-top" : "29px","height" : "49px"});
        });
        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
           jQuery(document).ready(function() {
           var html = $("#tab10 a").html().split(" ");
           html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
           jQuery("#tab10 a").html(html);
           jQuery("#tab10 a").css({"line-height" : "16px","text-align" : "center","padding-top" : "29px","height" : "49px"});
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: Why are they in separate script tags?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be any more efficient performance-wise, but it would be more efficient maintenance-wise.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about code review

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Btw, you shouldn't separate into different script blocks.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
  var tabs = ["tab7", "tab9", "tab10"];
  jQuery.each(tabs, function(index, value){
    var el = $("#"+value+" a");
    var html = el.html().split(" ");
    html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
    el.html(html);
    el.css({"line-height" : "16px","text-align" : "center","padding-top" : "29px","height" : "49px"});
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

It would be much better to cut this down into a single handler using a common class for all of your items

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
       $(".tab a").each(function() {
           var html = $(this).html().split(" ");
           html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
           $(this).html(html);
       });
    });
```

And then you would apply the following CSS to the page :

```
<style type="text/css">
.tab a {
    line-height:16px;
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:29px;
    height:49px;
}
</style>
```

This way every `<a>` element with in an element with `class='tab'` will have the same style and the jQuery code is significantly shortened as jQuery will automatically find every element that matches the parameter and iterate through them using the `.each` method and apply the changes.

Comment: Why not a common class rather than a for loop so that you don't care about the start/stop value?

Comment: Thats a very good point actually, I'll add in an example for that.

Answer (score 1):

Without rewriting the script entirely, here are a few suggestions:

1. Place the JS in a separate JS file.
2. You don't need to separate the JS with multiple `<script>` blocks, and you don't need multiple ready functions.
3. In terms of consistency, use jQuery or $, not both
4. Since the code is being replicated, use a loop and replace the respective values.

It would look something like this in a separate .js file (minus the looping):

```
$(function () {
    var html = $("#tab7 a").html().split(" ");
    html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
    $("#tab7 a").html(html);
    $("#tab7 a").css({
        "line-height": "16px",
            "text-align": "center",
            "padding-top": "29px",
            "height": "49px"
    });

    html = $("#tab9 a").html().split(" ");
    html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
    $("#tab9 a").html(html);
    $("#tab9 a").css({
        "line-height": "16px",
            "text-align": "center",
            "padding-top": "29px",
            "height": "49px"
    });

    html = $("#tab10 a").html().split(" ");
    html = html[0] + "<br>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
    $("#tab10 a").html(html);
    $("#tab10 a").css({
        "line-height": "16px",
            "text-align": "center",
            "padding-top": "29px",
            "height": "49px"
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would add a class to the elements and hand each of them with the `.each` method. It iterates through every element of the array returned by the `.className` selector.

```
 $(function() {
    $(".tab-link").each(function(){
       var html = $(this).html.split(" ");
       html = html[0] + "<br/>" + html.slice(1).join(" ");
       $(this).html(html);
       $(this).css({"line-height" : "16px","text-align" : "center","padding-top" : "29px","height" : "49px"});
    });
 });
```

[JQuery Doc](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/)